# Constant issue infinite size

Tags: flutter

I;m busy the whole day fixing a very tedious problem.
I try to create a screen that show a large item of a newspost on top and beneath the following items in a grid, 2 by 2

I keep getting the message the constraint are not correct.

Please help:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:project/providers/dataprovider.dart';

import 'news_detail_screen.dart';

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewsScreen> createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    final dataProvider = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await dataProvider.fetchData();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataProvider = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context);
    final categories = dataProvider.categories;
    final filteredItems = dataProvider.filteredItems;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Nieuws',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Dosis'),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(30),
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: categories.map((category) {
                        final index = categories.indexOf(category);
                        final isSelected =
                            index == dataProvider.selectedCategoryIndex;

                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            dataProvider.setSelectedCategoryIndex(index);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: isSelected
                                  ? const Color(0xffac0000)
                                  : Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: const Color(0xffac0000),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              category,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (ctx, index) {
                      final itemIndex = index - 1;
                      if (itemIndex < 0) {
                        return _buildFirstItem(filteredItems[0]);
                      } else {
                        return _buildGridItem(filteredItems[itemIndex]);
                      }
                    },
                    childCount: filteredItems.length + 1,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFirstItem(Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewsDetailScreen(itemIndex: item['id']),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(200),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(item['image']),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 8,
              right: 8,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xffac0000),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  item['category_name'],
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  item['post_title'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(14),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGridItem(Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewsDetailScreen(itemIndex: item['id']),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(item['image']),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 8,
              right: 8,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xffac0000),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  item['category_name'],
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  item['post_title'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(14),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The data is coming in good with all the needed info but it is refusing to get it right.
I'm sure i overlook something but i cannot see it :(

Help is a lot appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try wrapping your CustomScrollView with SafeArea widget. Like SafeArea(child: CustomScrollView(....)).....